# Kohana 3.2 Cron in Cpanel not working

Tags: cron, cpanel, kohana

Hi I have set in my cpanel a cron job that runs every minute:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/mysite/public_html/index.php --uri="cron/test"
```

the cron above is going through my index.php because i'm logging it if it works although it doesn't go on my cron controller "cron/test"

in my index.php i am doing this for test purpose only and i am getting indexcalled.txt:

```
$fp = fopen('indexcalled.txt', 'a+');
fwrite($fp, "POST: " . serialize($_POST));
fwrite($fp, '-----------');
fwrite($fp, "GET:" . serialize($_GET) . "\r\n");
fclose($fp);
```

and in my Cron controller i have this, but im not getting crontest.txt

```
public function action_test() {
   $fp = fopen('crontest.txt', 'w+'); 
   fwrite($fp, date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "cron test initiating...\n\n");   
   fclose($fp);
}
```

Is there anything I am not doing right or I might have forgotten to set?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried curl command in cron job ?